# Why my make command still says "No targets ..."?

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I'm new to Makefile, and I tried to make a simplest Makefile. But I don't understand why even though I'm clearly in the correct path to the Makefile, the make command still says "make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop."?~

### Here is my Makefile content :

```
 CC=gcc
 CFLAGS=-I.

 exercise1: exercise1.c
     $(CC) -o exercise1 exercise1.c
```

---

files in ..TH\Week1 : exercise1.c, Makefile
[image]

Comment: Wow. I am already not a fan of pictures of text ( https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557 ) but a picture of what is largely no text, i.e. white background..... I am impressed.

Comment: you may require a single [tab] `\t` instead of N spaces to have `make` interpret it correctly

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any funny symbols in the makefile name?

Comment: Please don't use images: cut and paste text.  But, the problem must be that that file is not actually  named just `Makefile`.  Try running `ls Makefile`; does it say no such file?  Try renaming it to be sure it doesn't have any trailing spaces or similar.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, but "ls Makefie" return 1 result, that is my Makefile and there are no funny symbols in the Makefile name. Looks like problem come from my windows machine :D

Comment: I've never seen anything like that before.  You can try running `make -d` to see what it says.  You can also try running `make -f Makefile` but this should not be in any way necessary.

Comment: Try doing the same in the old good CMD and not powershell

Comment: The error says that make cannot find the makefile.  So, the content of the makefile (tabs vs. space) or the shell you use to invoke make shouldn't matter at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried copying the `Exercise1` folder to somewhere else, and it worked! I finally found the error. It's in the pathname to the Makefile. The path goes through a directory named `LT Mạng`, and it seems cmd/Powershell/Terminal can't read the special characters. Just change the name of this folder again, for example: `LT Mang`. It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following and see if it works. Make sure there is no typo in the names of the files or anything.

```
CC = gcc

exercise1: exercise1.c
    $(CC) -o $@ exercise1.c
```

Also try running make with a target name like this:

```
make exercise1
```

Comment: Maybe mention the all-time-favorite problem of tabulators...

Comment: It still doesn't work

Comment: @buzz Did you adjust the tabs and stuff? Also take a look at the edit

Comment: I have tried all the solutions that I can find. Looks like the problem is on my computer

Comment: @buzz are you on a windows machine? If so uninstalling and redownloading make could work. If you are not on windows, download homebrew (brew.sh) and type ```brew install make``` on terminal (or something).

Comment: Yes, I'm on windows machine. I'm trying to re-install make